# Azure Mobile Sync, data not updating

Tags: sqlite, synchronization, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services, offline

I have an iOS/Android application that is using Azure Mobile Sync. Most of the time everything works as you would expect but there is a scenario that is dogging me quite a bit. The scenario is:

Phone A creates a record. 
Phone B creates a record.
Phone A updates phone B's record.
Phone B updates phone A's record.
Phone C gets both record creation and the latest updates correctly from the cloud.
Phone A has it's original record but fails to pull in phone B's update.
Phone B has it's original record but fails to pull in phone A's update.

I have verified there are not sync conflicts and the data is being pulled and most of the time this doesn't happen. Mostly, phone A/B/C all get updated properly. I extracted the sqlite database from my Android phone and I've checked the `_operations` table and I do not see any sync operations for the records in question. It's like the system thinks it's already up to date and doesn't try to sync.

Is there a way to force pull everything from the cloud? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> It's like the system thinks it's already up to date and doesn't try to sync.
>
> Is there a way to force pull everything from the cloud? Thanks!

I assumed that you are using Incremental Sync describled as follows:

> **Incremental Sync**: the first parameter to the pull operation is a query name that is used only on the client. If you use a non-null query name, the Azure Mobile SDK performs an incremental sync. **Each time a pull operation returns a set of results, the latest updatedAt timestamp from that result set is stored in the SDK local system tables. Subsequent pull operations retrieve only records after that timestamp**.

Details you could follow [How offline synchronization works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync)
.

You could try to pass `null` as the query ID, then all records would be retrieved on every `PullAsync` request as follows:

```
await todoTable.PullAsync(null, syncTable.Where(u => u.xxx == "xxx"));
```

Moreover, you could leverage fiddler to capture the network traces when you encounter this problem, then you could inspect the specific request parameters to narrow this issue.